# android multiple choice using images

Tags: android

I have 10 images in an array which are answers to 10 questions which are also images in another array.

I have 10 image buttons coming up on my relative layout loaded with the 10 answer images. The answer array is answers[] and the questions array is questions[]. They correspond to each other, meaning that answers[1] is the answer to questions[1], and answers[4] is the answer to questions[4], and so on. I have a simple "for" statement which is `for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)`.

I want the 10 questions to come up one at a time, and let the user answer. I need the program to pause and let the user click the answer to the question. With that "for" statement, the first question which is questions[0] will pop up in imageview. Using if statements, I want to say "if the imagebutton with images[0] is clicked then I want an image to display that will say correct and do some other stuff, else I want an image to say incorrect and do some other stuff" and then I want it to pause until the user just clicks anywhere on the screen.

Can anyone help me with the pausing in the "for" statement to let the user answer, and the "if" statement where if the correct answer is picked I can display an image that says correct etc, and then pause again until the user just clicks anywhere on the screen?? Thanks!

By the way, I need those question images to pop up in the same imageview each time obviously, just changing the image.

Comment: Your question is not really a question - you're basically asking us to write your application for you. Since you don't have much Android experience, start with "Activity lifecycle" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control the program flow the way you want to with a for loop.  The user interface in Android is event-driven, so the only way to move from question to question is by reacting to the event that is generated when the user clicks a button.  You do that by finding the button and attaching an event handler for the click event, called `onClick`, which is a part of the View.OnClickListener interface.  You can define a variable on your activity class to store which question you're on and use that to step your way through as the user answers questions.  Your activity might look something like this:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  public int currentQuestion = 0;
  Image[] answers;
  Image[] questions;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Load questions and answers
      setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
      final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
      button.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View view)
  {
      if (/* the answer is correct */) {
          // happiness: show images, do what needs doing
      } else {
          // sadness: show other images, etc
      }
      currentQuestion++;
  }

}
```